# Failed to load resource in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Consider this code:

```
  function drawCharts2() {
  var jsonData2 = $.ajax({
      url: "http://**.**.**.**:9001/jolokia/read/*",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

     var parsed2 = JSON.parse(jsonData2);
```

The above URL contains no value at the startup of the web app. The data in that url will come after 2-3 minutes.

When I start my web app. It gives error, but as a workaround I have set my page refresh time to 30 seconds. So after 30 seconds the table generates successfully.

I need a way so that, even if the url will not contain any data, the code should not give any error. It should just skip the whole code. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use the success callback of the Ajax call: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var parsed2;
        function drawCharts2() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://**.**.**.**:9001/jolokia/read/*",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                     if(response) {
                       parsed2 = response;
                     } 
                    else
                         {   drawCharts2();  // retry if you want to..     }
                    },
                    error: function (event) {

                        alert("Transmission Failed. (An error has occurred)");
                    }
                });
      if( parsed2 != null)
      {
      var arr2 = []; for(var x in parsed2)
      { arr2.push(parsed2[x]);
        } 
        var array_keys = new Array(); 
        var array_values = new Array();
         }
   }
```

Comment: Actually after the above code, the code goes like this:

          `var parsed2 = JSON.parse(jsonData2);

   var arr2 = [];

   for(var x in parsed2){
     arr2.push(parsed2[x]);
   }
   
   var array_keys = new Array();
   var array_values = new Array();
 `

Comment: So if I do this  `if (response != "") {
                    var parsed2 = JSON.parse(response);
                }`
it wont be able to read that variable further.

Comment: Modified the code above and parsed2 is declared outside the ajax call

Comment: But its not hitting the URL agin after 5 secs. I have this piece at the end. `chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 200, showRowNumber: true, allowHtml: true});
  setTimeout(drawChart, 5000);`